# Will Request.UserHostName always give me the user's computer name?

Tags: .net, http-headers

Basically I want to make sure I will always get the computer's name rather than any proxy or other hardware imbetween.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you cannot.

Everything the server knows about a client is only through the user agent string which the browser supplies, since users can change the user agent string and proxies may strip or modify it you cannot make any assumptions on it.

Comment: Not only the user agent string.  Also http headers.   Still, your "No" answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's always possible.  If a user is using an anonymous proxy, there's really nothing you can do.