# How can I get in c# the name of the computer, I need the name and not the IP

Tags: c#, helper

`HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name` it's given the user name

```
txtUserIP.Text = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress
```

it's given the IP

and I need:

1. the name of the computer
2. aplicative user

it's need to start with: `HttpContext`

Comment: You need the name of the client computer?

Comment: You cannot get it using the HttpContext, it isn't sent in the request

Comment: Are you trying to do this in a LAN environment or over the internet?

Comment: I need the name of the client computer

Comment: @user177912 - Yes, I realize that but is the client computer in the same network as the server or are you trying to do this across the internet?

Answer (score 1):

UserHostName gets the DNS name of the client, is that sufficient?

edit

Oskar originally, and quite correctly, linked another question in his comment pointing out that you cannot assume this variable is set, the server gets it data from the UserAgent header in the request and this data in particular is stripped out a lot (anonymous proxies etc) so yes it may be available, no you cannot assume it is

Comment: Probably the closest you will get

Comment: so what can I do? do i need to get the name of the computer by string from client side and pass the string to the service?

Comment: This is the link btw http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333907/will-request-userhostname-always-give-me-the-users-computer-name

Comment: @user177912 The problem is that you cannot. It's a security measure

Comment: basically what Oskar said, you cant get the data that the client does not send, if you have control of the environment i.e LAN no firewalls it should be there though once you are dealing with the internet it is pretty much a no go

Comment: the client wont that these parameters will writen to log file.

Comment: @user177912 Unfortunately, unless you control both ends of the conversation this is not really feasable

Comment: what's diffrant between the user name, IP and the name of comcuter? why i can't get the name but I can get the other?

Comment: @user177912 IP is needed so the server responds to the right machine, username is dependent upon your authentication schema, f you where anonymous for instance you would not get it. Have you actually tried my solution, no one is saying it won't work it just may not, you have not given enough info regarding the environment to say for sure

Answer (score 0):

`HttpContext.Current.Server.MachineName` contains the name of the server.  You can't get the name of the client computer, as it isn't sent with a request.

Answer (score 0):

Can't do it with HttpContext. Could you use this?:

```
var IpToHost = Dns.GetHostEntry(ipaddress);
```

Comment: I understand that I can't do it in server side. can I get name of the computer at client side and pass the string through the layers?

Answer (score 0):

DNS host name of the local computer

```
String hostName = Dns.GetHostName();
```